# Converting OSM data to Prolog facts?

Tags: prolog, converters, openstreetmap

For a small experiment, I would like to transform an exported [OSM](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/) dataset from XML to Prolog.

I know there are certain general purpose XML to Prolog converters (e.g., [Pl4Xml](http://www.techrepublic.com/whitepapers/pl4xml-an-swi-prolog-library-for-xml-data-management/2358643)), but are these general purpose converters the best way to go for this problem ? probably someone knows about a library to convert OSM data to a **convenient** representation in Prolog ?

Answer (score 2):

Sergio, I don't know the best way. But I did my own small experiment with OSM. I didn't used Pl4XML but just SWI-Prolog with library(sgml). Like this:

```
tt2(tag, Attrs, _) :- 
   memberchk(k=Key, Attrs), 
   \+ tag(Key), assertz(tag(Key)), 
   fail ; true.

?- dynamic tag/1.
?- new_sgml_parser(Parser, []), 
   open('UA.osm', read, Stream), 
   sgml_parse(Parser, [source(Stream), call(begin, tt2)]), 
   free_sgml_parser(Parser), 
   close(Stream).
```

UA.osm is my XML data. I've got more 1000 different tag keys. It should be handled properly. I think the best way is to use predicates for OSM node, way and relation with a common `tags` member and represent a tags data as an ordered set of key-value pairs (or AVL trees). Because I am a developer of [Uranium Test](http://uranium-test.sourceforge.net) I think Uranium gives me the best object model for Prolog (not locked for particular Prolog implementation). I can give you the example how you can manage OSM object relations:

```
:- module(node_v, [on_begin/3, on_end/2]).
:- use_module(u(v)).

% helper for callback tag parsing
new_class(xml_tag_v, db_object_v, [closed_by_parser]).

% OSM element 
new_class(element_v, xml_tag_v,
      [id,
       changeset,
       visible,
       user,
       timestamp,
       tags]).

% OSM node, way and barrier - children of element
new_class(node_v, element_v, [lat, lon]).
new_class(way_v, element_v, [nodes]).
new_class(barrier_v, element_v, [barrier_type]).

% Example of a tag-based dynamic class
% (see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Barriers)
'element_v?'(Obj, class, barrier_v) :-
   obj_field(Obj, tags, Tags),
   % if it contains Key:barrier it is a barrier
   % (way or node)
   memberchk(barrier-_, Tags), !.

% XML parsing callbacks
on_begin(node, Attrs, _) :-
   % Construct the node_v object
   obj_construct(node_v, [], [], Obj),
   foreach(member(Name=Value, Attrs),
      obj_field(Obj, weak, Name, Value)),
   % Put it into DB 'nodes'
   db_recorda(nodes, Obj).

on_begin(tag, Attrs, _) :-
   db_recorded(nodes, Obj0), !,
   obj_rewrite(Obj0,
           [closed_by_parser, tags],
           [Is_Closed, Tags0],
           [Is_Closed, Tags], Obj),
   var(Is_Closed), !, % found unclosed node
   memberchk(k=Key, Attrs),
   memberchk(v=Value, Attrs),
   (  var(Tags0) -> Tags1 = [] ; Tags1 = Tags0 ),
   Tags = [Key - Value|Tags1], % add new tag
   db_recorda(nodes, _, Obj, _, replaced). % db update

on_end(node, _) :-
   % close the node parsing
   db_recorded(nodes, Obj0), !,
   obj_rewrite(Obj0,
           [closed_by_parser, tags],
           [_, Tags0],
           [true, Tags], Obj),
   (  var(Tags0) 
   -> Tags = [] 
   ; sort(Tags0, Tags) % if your expectation for a number of tags is big
                       % try use library(assoc) (AVL trees)
   ),
   db_put_object(nodes, _, Obj, _, replaced).
```

new_class/3 defines a class - it is a usual prolog term with a possibility of named access to values (with help of additional predicates) and lot of other things like inheritance, object database etc. The module defines three main OSM entities - `node_v`, `way_v` and `relation_v` (_v is a suffix for objects) as children of `element_v`. Each `element_v` contains the `tags` field.

`barrier_v` is an example how you can recognize OSM classes based on tag keys (or values). In this example a special predicate 'element_v?'/3 calculates a class of an object. barrier_v can be child of either node_v or way_v (not shown in this example).

The last part of the module is an XML (callback) parser. I tested it with ~1.7G file, it works well (SWI-Prolog).

nodes - is an object DB which is based on a standard prolog database (also external PostgreSQL can be used in future versions).

The example of one parsing result is:

```
?- db_recorded(nodes, N), obj_pretty_print(N), !.

N = node_v(70, '6176525', true, nodes, 32, '10980421', '46.4718061', '30.7308961', 
    [highway-traffic_signals], '2010-10-25T19:17:07Z', 'Buccaneer', _G391)

node_v ( 
  changeset : 6176525 
  closed_by_parser : true 
  db_key : nodes 
  db_ref : 32 
  id : 10980421 
  lat : 46.4718061 
  lon : 30.7308961 
  tags : [highway-traffic_signals] 
  timestamp : 2010-10-25T19:17:07Z 
  user : Buccaneer 
)
```

Also Uranium provides a lot of object/DB manipulation predicates, graph algorithmes and lot of other thinks. Sorry for not showing all this stuff on the project web site. We use Uranium mostly in commercial projects and the SF site is a child of my free time. But it is open source and we have lot of documentation and examples to share.

I hope my answer is useful.